# returning std::shared_ptr<Derived> from vector of std::shared_ptr<Base>

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I have an  `std::vector` of `shared_ptr<Base>` which contains many `shared_ptr<Derived>` objects. As a property of `Base`, each object has a `string` *name* for various reasons. I have a function `std::shared_ptr<Base> GetObjectByName(const char* name)` where I want to be able to return a derived component by evaluating if its name is the object Im looking for. What is the best way to get the `std::shared_ptr<Derived>` from the  `std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Base>>`

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `Base` and `Derived` are polymorphic (i.e. have at least one virtual function), you can use [`std::dynamic_pointer_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/pointer_cast):

```
std::shared_ptr<Base> pBase = GetObjectByName("name");
std::shared_ptr<Derived> pDerived = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(pBase);
```

Comment: Well, I would prefer `auto`.

Comment: The types are given for better exposition.

Comment: auto is semantically more difficult to read in this explanation.